# Recommendations on Installing our app on Surface Pro (3+)

Tags: windows, windows-installer, surface, appx, surface-pro

We have built a working MSI/application for desktop .  The client is requesting feasibility  to install on a few Surface Pro (3+) devices and I’m not knowledgeable at all about how this may be different. We can create appx, but we really want to have to avoid the store. Must we install through the store? We also don’t have or intend a MDM solution as we are an outside contractor.  Is side loading the only option? Or is there a better approach?

For the iOS devices we can use enterprise account and install by a single link to our servers by passing store and mdm , just a link.  Could there be something similar for windows?

Thanks

Comment: You should just be install the MSI without any problems. Only the new Windows 10 S devices are locked on installing apps just from the store.

Comment: And if its windows 10s? Can you sideload?

Comment: No, on Windows 10S devices you can install only apps from the store or store for business, not from a local share. At least not for the moment.

Comment: thanks @BogdanMitrache OK so , then to bypass store and install a MSI , one route is to upgrade windows to Pro? I also wonder if their admin IT can push an MSI

Comment: From what I know Surface Pro device come with Windows 10 Pro by default. The Windows 10 S device require an upgrade to Pro if the users want to install MSIs on them too, or other apps outside the Microsoft store.